# Meaning of all of the JNDI names in JBoss 7

Tags: jboss, jndi, jboss7.x

I'm deploying a Java EE application on JBoss 7.1.1, and when my session beans get deployed, JBoss prints out a message saying that it has created multiple JNDI bindings. Something like this:

```
java:global/ear-name/jar-name/MyClassImpl!fully.qualified.path.to.Interface
java:app/jar-name/MyClassImpl!fully.qualified.path.to.Interface
java:module/MyClassImpl!fully.qualified.path.to.Interface
java:jboss/exported/ear-name/jar-name/MyClassImpl!fully.qualified.path.to.Interface
java:global/ear-name/jar-name/MyClassImpl
java:app/jar-name/MyClassImpl
java:module/MyClassImpl
```

It varies a little bit from EJB to EJB, but that's the general idea.

I'm confused about what's going on here. Why are there so many of them? Is there a difference between these JNDI bindings? If there is, when should each of them be used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find all the documentation here [1] but in short some of it is dictated by spec and some are functionality specific to JBoss (mainly java:jboss/exported, java:jboss entries)

[1] https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JNDI%20Reference.html